# ReCharts: How to enable line animation if it is hidden in at the beginning?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

LineChart contains 2 Lines.
At the beginning one is shown and one is hidden.

Toggle buttons hide and show lines.

There is a difference between the lines. One of them is animated and the other is not.

How to animate the second line (the one that is hidden at the beginning)

live: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-moon-fdq9g?file=/src/Chart.jsx

Comment: The data is already loaded in your case. Thus animation doesn't work in the second scenario.

Answer (score 2):

In order to active animation for the draw of the second line, you have to load it on demand instead of working with the property hide because the data is already loaded and the animation was applied by the first line (i think its an issue in the library)

Here is a solution, that you can make better by managing the display of lines by loading or removing lines instead of changing the display property:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/modest-wilbur-ql18f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark